# Why this two function created by forkIO in haskell can't be run one by one?

Tags: haskell

I have this prog in windows ghc:

```
import Control.Concurrent

a=print 1
b=print 2

main=do
 forkIO a
 forkIO b
```

it can only print 1 in console,Why?

I think the main thread run first,then it create a thread,run function a,print 1,then create another thread,run function b,then print 2

so the console will give me

1
2

Comment: I think we need more details; you are correct about what it *should* do.  How are you compiling and running it?

Comment: It's very easy.the prog is a.hs.so just "ghc a.hs",then it's compling,give me a.exe,then run a.exe

Comment: Interesting, I am able to reproduce here on my Mac.  Maybe this is "correct" behavior somehow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I think I remember something about "a Haskell program ends when the main thread exits".  So the main thread is ending before the other threads have had a chance to do their thing.  A quick fix is

```
main = do
    forkIO a
    forkIO b
    threadDelay (10^6)  -- 1 second
```

A less quick, more correct fix is to use `MVar`s to simulate "joining" a thread -- i.e. waiting until it completes.